# Stop image texture from stretching (Blender)

Tags: 3d, modeling, blender

Hi i just recently started introducing images as textures in cycles rendered and i've realised that after unwrapping the object and applying the material the material is applied as one single image, so when i increase the size of the object the image becomes stretched out and obviously a much lower resolution, is there a way to duplicate the image rather then it stretching like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a mapping node to adjust the uv mapping in cycles.

[image]

The thing to remember with repeating an image is that you need to make sure it is repeatable or you will clearly see seams between repeats.

Also there is a [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) now.